# Coding difference between linear and cubic model

Tags: r

I have two variables ENERGY and TEMP

I have created two other variables temp2 and temp 3

```
 > temp2 <- data$temp^2
 > temp3 <- data$temp^3
 >data=cbind(data, energy, temp,temp2,temp3)
```

Now to create a cubic model would it look just like a linear model?

```
 >model<-lm(energy~temp+temp2+temp3)
```

Edit:

Ok so I did what you suggested and this is the output:

```
 > ?poly
 > model<- lm( energy ~ poly(temp, 3) , data=data ) 
 > summary(model)

 Call:
 lm(formula = energy ~ poly(temp, 3), data = data)

 Residuals:
     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -19.159 -11.257  -2.377   9.784  26.841 

 Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept)       95.50       3.21  29.752  < 2e-16 ***
 poly(temp, 3)1   207.90      15.72  13.221 2.41e-11 ***
 poly(temp, 3)2   -50.07      15.72  -3.184  0.00466 ** 
 poly(temp, 3)3    81.59      15.72   5.188 4.47e-05 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

 Residual standard error: 15.73 on 20 degrees of freedom
 Multiple R-squared: 0.9137,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.9008 
 F-statistic: 70.62 on 3 and 20 DF,  p-value: 8.105e-11
```

I would assume that I would test for the goodness of fit test the same way and look at the Pr(>|t|). This would lead me to believe that all of the variables are significant.

would I be able to use this fitted regression model to predict the average energy consumption for an average difference in temperature?

Comment: You can also use `lm(y ~ var + I(var^2) + I(var^3))`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of coding up dummy variable you should consider using the `poly` function:

```
?poly   # Polynomial contrasts
model<- lm( energy ~ poly(temp, 3) , data=data )
```

If you want to use the same columns as you would have gotten with the dummies approach (which is not good for statistical inference purposes), you can use the 'raw' parameter:

```
model.r<- lm( energy ~ poly(temp, 3, raw=TRUE) , data=data )
```

Predictions will be the same, but the standard errors will not. This should give you the same estimates as would be returned by @RomanLuštrik's suggestion. The terms will not be orthogonal, so their necessary correlations will be high and you will be unable to make correct inferences about independent effects.

Added question: "would I be able to use this fitted regression model to predict the average energy consumption for an average difference in temperature?"

No. You would need to specify a particular two temperatures and then `predict` could give you a difference, but that difference will vary depending on what the reference point is, even if the magnitude of the difference is the same.. That was a consequence of using a non-linear term.  Maybe you should describe your goals and use a forum that is more geared to methods questions. SO is for coding when you know what you want to do. http://stats.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate when you have formulated your question with more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have updated my question with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do polynomial regression with `lm`:

```
lm( y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) )
```

and

```
lm( y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE) )
```

(That's cubic. I'm sure you can generalise to quartic, quintic, etc.)